# REPLACE In oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, case

I need your help for REPLACE( in Oracle .
I need to replace many character in one column in my test it's ok for change 5 to 'test' if I want change again 5 & 4, you have a solution ?

[image]

Comment: Please provide the query, data and expected output as text (not image).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match on the entire value, I would recommend a `case` expression, which can easily be extended.

Say you want to transcode both `4` and `5` to "TEST":

```
case when resource_state_key in (4, 5) then 'TEST' end as val
```

Or if you want a different value:

```
case resource_state_key
    when 4 then 'TEST'
    when 5 then 'TEST2'
end as val
```

In Oracle, the latter can also be expressed with vendor-specific function `decode()`:

```
decode(resource_state_key, 4, 'TEST', 5, 'TEST2') as val
```

Comment: why not `replace( replace( resource_state_key, 4, 'TEST' ), 5, 'TEST' )` ?

Comment: @TaaviTiitsu: it seems like the OP wants to match on the entire input value (which, presumably, is a number), so `replace()` is not appropriate. What if the value was `45`? Your code would return `'TESTTEST'`, which - I suppose - is not what the OP wants. Also, `case` scales better if there are a lot of values to transcode (while `replace()` requires nesting the function calls).

Answer (score 0):

I don't consider what you want to do as a string operation.  Instead, it seems like you want to lookup a value in a reference table.  You should have a "resource state" reference table in the database.

If you don't have one in the database you can generate one in the query:

```
with resource_state_ref as (
      select 4 as resource_state_key, 'TEST' as val union all
      select 5 as resource_state_key, 'TEST' as val 
     )
select ref.val, t.*
from t left join
     resource_state_ref ref
     on t.resource_state_key = ref.resource_state_key
```